# Display form on button click

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build an application where a user can press abutton in the right top corner ( see image) that will hide one div (the topics) and display another div (a form where I can add a new topic).

This is what it looks like:
[image: How it looks like now]

```
if(isset($actiefboardid)){
  $toppic = $app->get_topics($actiefboardid);
    if(count($toppic)>0){
     foreach($toppic as $topic){
       echo "<div class='user-block'>";
        if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) {
          echo '<img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id']. '/' .$topic['foto'].'" />';
        } else {
          echo '<div class="fancyimg"><i class="img-circle img-bordered-sm fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i></div>';
        } 
          echo "<span class='username'><a href='https://tom.lbmedia.nl/boards/".$url[1]."/".$topic['url']."'>". $topic['topicnaam'] . "</a>
           </span><span class='description'>
           <span style='float:right;margin-left:5px;'>".implode($app->count_reactie($topic['id'])) ." reacties
           </span> 
           <span style='float:right; color:lightgrey;' class='fa fa-comment'></span>
           <span class='badge bg-red' style='border-radius: 5px;'>" . implode($app->boards($topic['board_id'])) . "
           </span>
           laatste reactie: " .$app->tijd_reactie($topic['id']) . " door " .$app->reactieDoor($topic['id'])."</div></span>
           <hr></hr>
           <p></p>
             <form class='form-horizontal'>
               <div class='form-group margin-bottom-none'>
               </div>                        
             </form>
            ";
            } 
          } else {
            echo "Er zijn nog geen topics  bij dit board";
          }
```

This is the code to display the topics. Now I need to implement the button described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide the form and the topic when firing click event.
So first time, show the topic and hide the form, and after clicking, toggle them

Comment: I kinda get what you mean, but how do I do that in my case?

Comment: You need to study JavaScript too, also you can use a library to ease your coding like JQuery or AngularJS.
for example, JQuery have two functions that can help you, click() and show()/hide() https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

From a high level perspective:

- This is client-side functionality, so do this in Javascript, not PHP
- Declare a variable in Javascript (such as `var showTable = true`)
- Create a CSS class that adds `{display: hidden}` to an HTML tag
- When the user clicks on the button, add the CSS class to the appropriate `<div`>

While this can be done in pure Javascript, using a library such as jQuery or Angular will make this task much easier for you.

jQuery Example:

```
// In your CSS file
.hidden {
  display: hidden;
}

// In your JS File
var showTable = true;
$('#myButton').click(function() {
 showTable = !showTable;
 if (showTable) {
   $('#div1').addClass('hidden');
   $('#div2').removeClass('hidden');
 else {
   $('#div2').addClass('hidden');
   $('#div1').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Comment: The point I get how I can show and hide things in Javascript but how do I make it that when I press the button it won't display the topics

Comment: Using the above code, wrap your topics around in a div as such:

 `<div id="div1><!-- YOUR TOPICS HERE --></div>`

Comment: And it will make it hidden then but it will not show me the form??

Comment: Your form is `<div id="div2">`

Comment: The code above should do what you want. Though obviously it goes without saying, you should give your id's better names than "div1" and "div2" :)

Comment: I tried this:: `<div id="div1">
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
This is my DIV element.
</div>
                            
<div id="div2">
Hallo mark
</div>

 
                        <script>
var showTable = true;
$('#myButton').click(function() {
 showTable = !showTable;
 if (showTable) {
   $('#div1').addClass('hidden');
   $('#div2').removeClass('hidden');
 else {
   $('#div2').addClass('hidden');
   $('#div1').removeClass('hidden');
}
                        </script>` and added the css but didnt do anything

Comment: First of all, you don't need the `onclick` with jQuery, all of that is handled. Second of all, make sure you have jQuery properly working. I'm worried we're getting a bit too out of scope for this question so if you have any further issues about getting jQuery to work, you should go to the documentation (http://jquery.com/) or look at other similar questions here on SO.

Comment: You can just tell me what I am doing wrong? I pasted the JQeury in my php document with `<script>` tags around it

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, in other words, it's added functionality beyond native javascript. As such, it must be added to your project in order to use, so your browser can understand it. Add this under your <head> tag: <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: For any additional questions on jQuery, I'd recommend this tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp). You can also find tons of answers here on SO, or you can ask another question if need be.